# Is there any way to trace through the execution of a batch file?

Tags: winapi, refactoring, batch-file, environment

I inherited some large batch files, and I'd like to rewrite them to a more "developer friendly" language.

I'd like to find out the following things:

- what other scripts it calls
- what other processes it starts
- what files does it write to
- what environment variables it uses, which ones does it set

For the last point, I'm aware I can do this before I start:

```
set > original_environment.txt
```

And after I run it, I can do this:

```
set > new_environment.txt
```

and just do a diff between them ... but I'll probably miss some variables that may be unset when the script finishes ( or even all of them if the script's ran under `setlocal` ).

Is there any way of finding all those things without me adding tons of echo statements throughout the script code? 
Is there such a tool that can monitor the process started by the batch file and tell me everything it did?

Comment: Rewrite them in PowerShell. It has debugging capability. You can also use the excellent "PowerShell Plus" product from Idera, and get an interactive debugging experience.

Comment: @John: I think the OP's problem was more understanding what the batch file dod to rewrite it in another language. So you're kinda making the same point again :)

Comment: You can get some of this info from Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx, but as for the rest. I hope you find something, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: I understand what the batch does, and if I read through it I'm able to reproduce it, but I was thinking about a tool which reports as much of those things as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can just look inside them and figure out what they do.

You can also remove any `echo off` statements and `@` preceding commands; that way every command is output before it's run and you can redirect the output to a file to study it later.

There is no debugging tool for batch files that I am aware of—but I contemplated writing one once.

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to make sure all other scripts getting called also don't have the `echo off`. I'm thinking about the same thing about the tool :)

Comment: @Geo: The problem with such a tool would be that you have to accurately model cmd's behavior. And you can't just execute the lines one-by-one in cmd since that has often different results than when run from a batch file—a naïve approach would likely fail. Although I think I have an idea which *could* work—you simply write out another batch file, containing a `pause` statement after each line as well as writing the complete environment into a file for the debugger to grab. Might not be too pretty and keeping track of open files is another problem entirely. Process Monitor was a nice tip, though

Answer (score 2):

**There is no direct way to do it. But it's not impossible to create one.**

Since Windows XP/Vista/7 came out the good'ole set of DOS batch commands has been greatly upgraded, although not many uses them or even RTFM (`FOR /?`?)

So here I give you, a simple pure-batch TRACER that utilizes the `FOR /F` line-parsing switch:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "delims=" %%L IN (%1) DO (

  CLS

  ECHO __________________________________________________
  ECHO                            ENV. VARIABLES *BEFORE*
  SET

  ECHO __________________________________________________
  ECHO                                               LINE
  ECHO %%L

  ECHO __________________________________________________
  ECHO Hit any key to execute the line ...
  PAUSE > NUL

  ECHO __________________________________________________
  ECHO                                            EXECUTE
  %%L

  ECHO __________________________________________________
  ECHO Hit any key to fetch the next line...
  PAUSE > NUL

)

ECHO END OF FILE
```

You can take it as a start and modify it as you go.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
DEBUG.BAT TEST.BAT
```

And I'll also give you a test file to try it out:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Hello World! 
SET aaa=1
SET bbb=2

ECHO Doing step 2
SET aaa=
SET ccc=3

ECHO Doing step 3
SET bbb=
SET ccc=

ECHO Finished!
```

---

This `DEBUG.BAT` thing, however, due of its simplicity, has some limitations *BUT* which can be worked around if you slap enough BATCH-fu in there.

- **It cannot process multi-line blocks** :: This can be worked around by having the `FOR` commands parse tokens and build the lines as they come in, and `IF` it encountered an open parenthesis, just dump the parenthesis block content to a temporary file and then call itself on the tempfile e.g. `DEBUG tempfile.bat`
- **It cannot process jumps** :: You can of course, do an `IF` check for a `GOTO label` then do a `FOR /F` to parse out label itself, then maybe utilize the second argument `%2`of `DEBUG.BAT` to specify the label to jump to, in which case if this very argument is specified you'd just spin the `FOR /F` until the desired label came into view and then proceeds with normal debugging on the next line.
- **There is too much information from a single `SET`** :: Just do what you did with the `SET > before.txt` and after thing but do it on each line and then run a cmd-line DIFF tools on the files (plenty are available on the net). Then you'll get a DIFF of each variable that has changed since last step. You might even be able to avoid the env. variables mess altogether by slapping in `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` in there and then you'd get just the local SETs ... but YMMV.

Those are some. If you've found some show-stopping limitation or whatever enhancements would help you nail that last bug, feel free to just let me know (via the comments) and I'll try to help you if I can.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to debug old style batch files.  You can, however, just get rid of all the `ECHO OFF` statements, and then all the commands and output will be echo'd to the console when you run them.

Comment: Any line starting with @ will also not be echoed

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to spend some money you should take a look at the [Running Steps](http://www.steppingsoftware.com/ssportal/Product/tabid/54/Default.aspx) batch file IDE and its debugging capabilities.

I didn't test it, but it has some features that might help you in your task:

> ...
>
> - Visual Studio-like debugging environment.
> - Rich set of debugging commands (step into, step over, step out, and more)
> - Rich Project analyzer to find your errors and warnings in no time.
> - Integrated support for delayed-expanded environment
>   variables.
> - Multi-type breakpoint definitions to fit your multiple debugging needs.
> - Complex pipeline and redirection support with multi-color highlighting.
> - Environment variable visualization and modification support.
> - Expanded information window for true variable definition visualization.
> - Impressive 'For command' unrolling feature.
> - Interactive callstack and Parameters window.
>
> ...

They also offer a trial version.

Comment: The Running Steps link is now defunct - points to a portal site.