# Unable to execute maven command on jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, testng

I have a jenkins job that checks out code from TFS and executes a test class using testng.xml

I have Maven properly installed in my machine in C:\JenkinsDependencies\apache-maven

It has mvn.bat file in its bin folder.

But when I execute my job, it fails with the following error.

> Checking for pre-build
>   [TFS_LN_Mobile] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\JenkinsDependencies\apache-maven\bin\mvn.bat test && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
>
> Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
>
> Checking for post-build
>   Finished: FAILURE

Below is the configuration of my jenkins job:
[image]
**I manually executed a batch command as follows:**

```
cd "C:\JenkinsRoot\workspace\TFS_LN_Mobile"
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
```

This works fine.

Comment: do you have your JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME variables set for jenkins user?

Comment: On the slave machine where the code will be check out, I have set MAVEN_HOME AND JAVA_HOME set. What should M2_HOME point to?

Comment: M2_HOME=/path/to/maven-3.2.5, so that when it does PATH=PATH:M2_HOME/bin, your mvn.bat is there.

Comment: Should I append %M2_HOME%\bin in my PATH?

Comment: from your error message, it looks like Jenkins is able to find your maven. so just setting JAVA_HOME and adding it to PATH should be fine.

Comment: when you run it manually on the Jenkins server, do you use the same user?

Comment: I always use the same user

Comment: setting JAVA_HOME and adding %JAVA_HOME%/bin to PATH did not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90810/discussion-between-rameshwar-and-ilj).

Answer (score 1):

mvn.bat is a batch script. you can try adding trace of it's variables after steps that might produce this error. take a look at this: [Is there any way to trace through the execution of a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366280/is-there-any-way-to-trace-through-the-execution-of-a-batch-file)